# Using EZFontResolver (PDFsharp) throwing an exception when setting it

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, pdfsharp

I'm trying to include a private font into my PDFsharp (v1.51) document drawing process.

I'm using the `EZFontResolver` as explained [here](http://developer.th-soft.com/developer/2015/12/11/ezfontresolver-a-generic-font-resolver-for-pdfsharp-and-migradoc/)

Here is what I'm doing:

```
        public byte[] GetCertificate(Object model)
        {
            // Get the EZFontResolver.
            EZFontResolver fontResolver = EZFontResolver.Get;
            
            // Assign it to PDFsharp.
            GlobalFontSettings.FontResolver = fontResolver;  //HERE IT FAILS

            fontResolver.AddFont("Pinyon Script", XFontStyle.Regular, this.SpecialFontPath, true, true);

            // Create a new PDF document
            var document = new PdfDocument();
            document.Info.Title = "CERTIFICATE ";

...
```

The offending line is: `GlobalFontSettings.FontResolver = fontResolver;`
With the following error: `*Must not change font resolver after is was once used.*`

I have read that the issue is that as it is a Singleton, you should only set it once... but it is set before even creating the document, and I'm only setting it in this place (as I only use the font here).

Or it could be that it is masking another issue?

**Any idea of how can I walk around it?**

I used the sample project using the EZFontResolver class and it works, the only difference is that I'm running the problematic code from ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

The error message `*Must not change font resolver after it was once used.*` is quite clear.

Make sure you only set it once.

Maybe use a static boolean flag that indicates when the `FontResolver` was already set and skip the assignment in that case.